# Does $\operatorname{id} M =\dim R$ hold for finite modules of finite injective dimension?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, cohen-macaulay

When $\operatorname{id}R<∞$ then $\operatorname{id}R = \dim R$. The same holds for a finite *free*, *projective* or *flat* module instead of $R$, that is, $\operatorname{id}M = \dim R$. Does it hold for *finite* modules of finite $\operatorname{id}$? (Here $\operatorname{id}$ means *injective dimension* and $R$ is a Noetherian local ring.)

---

**edit**
As said in comments, this  is equivalent to Bass' question, and proved in "*On the ubiquity of Gorenstein rings*". But the way to reach it is pretty long, specially regarding old terminology. I wonder if there is a direct proof for it? ( based on books like  *Matsumura*'s and *Bruns_Herzog*'s)

Comment: @ucf: the example by user121097 gives an example of a finite non-flat module where the equality in your title does not hold, which answers your second question. On the other hand, a finitely generated flat module over a Noetherian ring is projective, which answers your first question

Comment: Just to be clear (Bass has other conjectures), Bass' question was: if $R$ is Noetherian local with a finite module of finite injective dimension, then $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay. ucf's question is equivalent to this, because of the following fact: if $M$ is finite and $\text{injdim}(M) < \infty$, then $\text{injdim}(M) = \text{depth}(R)$.

Comment: Lemma 3.3 of *On the ubiquity of Gorenstein rings* says that for a local ring $R$ and nonzero finitely generated $R$-module $M,$ if $\operatorname{injdim}_R(M) < \infty,$ then $\operatorname{injdim}_R(M) = \operatorname{depth}(R).$ But how do you conclude that $\operatorname{depth}(R) = \operatorname{dim}(R)$?